# How can I use Azure Data Studio's SQL formatting with DBeaver?

Tags: format, code-formatting, dbeaver, azure-data-studio

I really love DBeaver as a database query tool, but I don't like the default SQL formatting that is has.

I'm wondering if it's possible to point to the SQL formatting that is used by Azure Data Studio? DBeaver allows you to use External formatters, but I'm not really sure how or if I can point to something within the Azure Data Studio to leverage it's format tools.

If I can't use Data Studio, could you suggest some other ways to use external SQL formatting with DBeaver? I'm currently using the Poor Man's SQL Formatter 1.6.10 and it's okay, but not as customizable as I'd like.

Thanks for any help / advice with this.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a late answer, but there is an external formatter (SQLinForm) for DBeaver which can be found [here](https://www.sqlinform.com/free-dbeaver-sql-formatter/)

Comment: I like this but it's Freemium. I'd prefer to use poor mans SQL but I can't figure out how to do that through DBeaver. Do you know? I have it downloaded and I set the External Formatter to `"C:/Users/me/Downloads/SqlFormatter.1.6.10/SqlFormatter.exe" ${file}` but it doesn't format.

Comment: Here's a link to the GitHub page where I asked this too. https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/285